# Filter Student class based on enum

Tags: java, class, enums, compare, abstract

I have an abstract class `Human` and a derived class `Student`
 - The `Human` class has a first name and last name field. 
 - The `Student` class  has a new field called 'type', which is an enumeration that has the options **PRIMARY**, **SECONDARY** and **COLLEGE**, and average grade field, which is the student's average grades for the year.

I need help with defining the `Student` class with the enumeration. I tried with this:

```
public class Student extends Human {

    private int averageGrade;

    public enum TYPE {

        PRIMARY(1), SECONDARY(2), COLLEGE(3);

        private int studentType;

        TYPE(int stType) {
            studentType = stType;
        }

        public int GetStudentType() {
            return studentType;
        }

        public void SetStudentType(int value) {
            if (value != 1 || value != 2 || value != 3) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(" dsfss");
            }
            this.studentType = value;
        }

        public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int studentType, int averageGrade) {
            super(firstName, lastName);

            this.setAverageGrade(averageGrade);
        }

        public int getAverageGrade() {
            return averageGrade;
        }

        public void setAverageGrade(int averageGrade) {
            if (averageGrade < 2 && averageGrade > 6) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Student grades are between 2 and 6 inclusive");
            }
            this.averageGrade = averageGrade;
        }


}
```

Also I have to print the student with the highest grade from each student type (**PRIMARY**, **SECONDARY** and **COLLEGE**).

I don't know what kind of Comparator to use for the enum, the `averageGrade` is easy, but first I need to sort them based on the type enum.

Please help! I will be grateful.

Comment: I can't read your code! Could you please properly indent it?

Comment: I formatted the code part, needs to be reviewed though.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better create TYPE in a different file, like StudentType and then add an atribute to the class body of Student. Then you'll have something like this:

```
public class Student {

    private String firstName, lastName;
    private Integer averageGrade;
    private StudentType studentType;

    // getters and setters

}
```

And an enum like this:

```
public enum StudentType {
    PRIMARY, SECONDARY, COLLEGE;
}
```

You can use compareTo(E o) method to compare two enums (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#compareTo(E)).
You can use compareTo(Integer anotherInteger) to compare to integers (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo(java.lang.Integer)).

For exemple:

```
public class StudentComparator  implements Comparator<Student>{

    public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
        // ASC comparing on attribute studentType
        int resultType = s1.getStudentType().compareTo(s2.getStudentType());
        if (resultType == 0) {
            // DESC comparing on attribute average grade
            return s2.getAverageGrade().compareTo(s1.getAverageGrade()); 
        } 
        return resultType; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Student("A", "A", 10, StudentType.COLLEGE));
        list.add(new Student("B", "B", 1, StudentType.COLLEGE));
        list.add(new Student("C", "C", 9, StudentType.PRIMARY));
        list.add(new Student("D", "D", 7, StudentType.SECONDARY));
        list.add(new Student("E", "E", 8, StudentType.PRIMARY));


        Collections.sort(list, new StudentComparator());

        for (Student student : list) {
            System.out.println(student);
        }
    }

}
```

The output will be:

```
C C at PRIMARY: 9
E E at PRIMARY: 8
D D at SECONDARY: 7
A A at COLLEGE: 10
B B at COLLEGE: 1
```